# Why are different Agadot in different masechtot

Tags: talmud-gemara, agada-stories-legends

I once heard that the agadot of each masechta are in that particular masechta fora reason.
does anyone know the source of such a claim

Comment: They tie into the sugyos which pertain to the masechtos they are in. Or once a certain personality says one idea, the gemara might quote a few more from him.

Comment: there is someone who stresses that all the agadot etc, not only those that slip in as you suggest

Comment: The only way anyone *could* know is by consulting the authors of the gemara.

Comment: i'm looking for the sefer that explicitly writes that they are not there by chance rather they are intimately connected to the masechta

Comment: This idea is exemplified on every page of _Ein Aya_ by Rav Kook. He also explains the underlying methodology in _Oros Ha_. . . something. Probably _Torah_.

Comment: @WAF Sounds like you have an answer....

Comment: I believe there's supposed to be a Gr"a to that effect. (Possibly in reference to why the churban habayis is in gitin.)

Comment: I also thought Iתd heard it from the Gra but am looking for the source.